# Maximum Time of Post Delayed

Tags: java, android, timer, runnable, android-handler

I have this method:

```
public static Runnable runAtDate(Date date, final TimerCallback callback)
{
    Date now = new Date();
    long timeTo = date.getTime() - now.getTime();

    if (timeTo <= 0)
    {
        if (callback != null)
            callback.onRun();
    }
    else
    {
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (callback != null)
                    callback.onRun();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, timeTo);
        return runnable;
    }

    return null;
}
```

This works fine when the date is around a few hours later (1, 2, 3) but around 8 hours this method does not work anymore. And since other timers have not been reliable (delayed and whatnot) I chose to use this, because it always execute right on time - when it works.

My question is, what is the maximum hours that a postDelay can run? Do I have to add a new postDelay every (some hours) adding the difference between (some hours) and the exact date?

Comment: use `postAtTime` instead, note that posted `Runnables` are forgotten when your app process is killed by the OS, why dont you want to use `AlarmManager`?

Comment: App is not killed after whatever MAX_HOUR is but it doesn't get executed eitherway. I'll look at postTime, haven't even thought about it. BUt, since the app is not killed - there seems to be some kind of time limit, which still would be nice to know.

Comment: there is no such limit, see the [sources](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java#533), why dont you want to use `AlarmManager`?

Comment: @pskink checking the sources of Looper, it seems that postDelayed just eventually calls sendMessageAtTime,  which is exactly what postAtTime does, so there's no difference. http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#565

Comment: @GregEnnis no difference in what?

Comment: @Deukalion I am facing the same problem. Have you found a solution?